# Magento How to Add Product attribute of dropdown with Key Value Pair

Tags: magento, attributes

I tried to add a new "product attribute" of dropdown type filed in Magento, i am able to add my dropdown values, but what i need is to add the dropdown as Key => value pair, these key values are used by NAV System. So, how can we achieve this ??

Let me explain with an example :

S.No    Key Value
1   IND India
2   AUS Australia
3   NZ  New Zealand

Now, i am able to to insert values(India, Australia, New Zealand,...) ; Now i need to insert Keys ( IND, AUS, NZ,...) Because i have to send these key values to NAV System(ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_NAV), as we integrated magento with NAV.

Comment: That depends what do you need as a return value. I understand you need result an array like array(color => red)? In frontend or in order?
If you need more keys and more values to product atributes for customer selection simple make more dropdowns, or select multiselect field input for more values on one key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Magento natural function of Magento.
When you setting values to Magento EAV attribute (Catalog / Attributes / New Attribute / Values (on left)), there are fields named Admin, Default Store view etc... 
There you set admin value NZ and for default store view set New Zeland, in export/import value will be saved as NZ. New Zeland will be visible only to customer on frontend.